# Vista/Win7 Listview "View Slider"

Tags: winapi, listview, windows-7, windows-vista

In Vista and Windows 7 almost any time the system uses a standard Listview (ie: Explorer Windows) it's accompanied by a little split button that shows a slider when the split is clicked that allows you to switch between the different views available for that listview (Tile, Details, List, etc.) as well as sliding smoothly between icon sizes (from 32x32 is to 256x256) using the top half of the slider.

This is a cool little bit of functionality, so I was wondering: Is that control available to developers, and if so what is it called and where is it documented? (Win32/C++ preferred)

Comment: Are you talking about the zoom slider menu?

Comment: I suppose so, is that what it's called? That would seem odd, since it does more than just zoom...

Comment: I'd post a picture if I could, but I don't have access to a Vista/7 machine right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in Windows 7, the explorer window is no longer a standard listview (though it does an extremely good job of looking like one). Open Spy++, point it at an explorer window list pane, and you'll see a classname of "DirectUIHWND" instead of the old "SysListView32".

The actual slider itself is indeed a real ComCtl32 slider; so you could perhaps roll your own; but as far as I know there's no way to reuse the existing explorer pane's functionality.